# VS code bash starts to show these ASCII characters when activating new environment using the conda activate ./envs command

Tags: bash, visual-studio, ascii, conda

The following commands were used to create and activate the environment in a specific location.
but after activating the environment the text of the bash terminal changes to ASCII characters highlighted in the below image.

```sh
conda create --prefix ./envs
conda activate ./envs
```

[image: look at the highlighted section]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue in VS Code while creating a virtual environment due to some cache issue. The solution for this is:

1. Close VS Code and Open GitBash
2. Then type in the following cmd:

     `rm ~/.condarc`
3. This cmd will remove the runtime configuration file.

   If it says "No such file or directory found", then also no issues.
4. Now type the following cmd:

    `conda config --set env_prompt '({name})'`
5. Now open VS Code and activate the env. The Problem will be solved.

   This command will change your env name (which was the entire filepath) to just the base name (env folder name)

**Hope this solution helps. If you have any queries just ping me.**